# Сложить два очень длинных char* как int. Каким образом?

Tags: c++, linux

Есть например два указателя:

```
char* a = "500";
char* b = "777";
```

Задача научит компьютер их складывать как числа. Загвоздка в том, что может быть вариант:

```
char* c = "99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999";
```

Я не думаю что он поместится в стандартные типы. Как быть?
Может есть какая то библиотека(желательно под Linux) для работы с гигантскими числами?

Пробовал писать свой класс, наделал кучу ошибок. Не хочется изобретать велосипед.

Comment: А библиотека GNU MP не спасёт отца русской демократии?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

это раздел [длинная арифметика](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Вот [здесь](http://acmp.ru/article.asp?id_text=1329) написано побольше и есть задачи с онлайн проверкой.

 Вот [здесь](http://www.cyberforum.ru/attachment.php?attachmentid=18011&d=1262799409) есть примеры.

Answer (score 1):

Есть. Это Длинная Арифметика. Вот и ищи библиотеки по этому запросу. 
Я когда был в школе писал такие под Паскаль.

В Java и Ruby, кстати, работают с такими числами стандартными средствами.

Comment: И python

Comment: Спасибо, направил на путь истинный :).

Comment: python я тестировал с одним челом. я написал на руби программу для вычисления факториала 1000 и он на питоне. вообщем питон слёг. может он что-нить не так писал. на руби это выглядит (0..1000).inject{|a,b|a*b}

Answer (score 0):

Java [BigInteger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Answer (score -1):

Вопрос конечно интересный, но он сводится к тому как CHAR массив представить как массив INT, после чего разбить его на части с каждой из которых работать по отдельности....

Comment: <i>но он сводится к тому как CHAR массив представить как массив INT</i>
А зачем? По-моему вполне возможно и работать со строчками напрямую :-) Не забываем, что CHAR - это тоже число :-)